# При добавлении данных в Dictionary получаю ошибку

Tags: c#

При добавлении в Dictionary, некоторых данных
p

```
public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string,Dictionary<int,float>>> check = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, float>>>();
    check[player.Username]["spawn"][0] = x;
    check[player.Username]["spawn"][1] = y;
    check[player.Username]["spawn"][2] = z;
```

Получаю ошибку

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Адресат вызова создал исключение. ---> System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: Данный ключ отсутствует в словаре.
   в System.ThrowHelper.ThrowKeyNotFoundException()
   в System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
```

Comment: в пустом словаре нет элемента с ключом `player.Username`.

Comment: а как его добавить?

Comment: добавить точно также, как и в любой другой словарь, надо только указать ключ и значение ключа, что добавляете

Comment: пример можно???

Comment: https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/4.9.php
https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2

Очень подробно описан ваш случай

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка происходит из-за попытки обращения к элементу в пустом массиве.

Для решения можно воспользоваться [инициализатором коллекции](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers)

например так:

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, float>>> check = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, float>>>()
{
    [player.Username] = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, float>>()
    {
        ["spawn"] = new Dictionary<int, float>()
        {
            [0] = x,
            [1] = y,
            [2] = z
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: при обращении или даже вывода всего массива получаю такое

Comment: `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.Int32,System.Single]]]`

Comment: @AnonimAnonim, как именно ты пытаешься вывести? :-) если просто вызываешь `ToString` - то стандартный результат, это имя класса, что ты и привел в своем комментарии.

Comment: `check[player.Username]["spawn"][0]` вот так обращаюсь

Comment: @AnonimAnonim, при таком обращении ты получишь значение `x`, и никак не можешь получить строку.

Comment: при таком обращении краш

Comment: @AnonimAnonim, очевидно, ты делаешь что-то не то. Посмотри пример кода в ответе. После выполнения того что в ответе - приведенное обращение корректно отрабатывает.

Comment: Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, float>>> check = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, float>>>
                {
                    [player.Username] = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, float>>()
                    {
                        ["spawn"] = new Dictionary<int, float>()
                        {
                            [0] = x,
                            [1] = y,
                            [2] = z
                        }
                    }
                };

Comment: для каждого игрока делаю так как выше

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85554/discussion-between-grundy-and-anonim-anonim).

Comment: потом при обращении `check[player.Username]["spawn"][0]`